# .net core 5.0 with IdentityServer4 returns for api method 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I setup my initial solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/stefancvetkovic/dotnet-api-with-identity-server-db-working/).

I setup swagger authorization as well as sql db user identity (program picks up correctly seeded data) and program lets me be authorized.
But When I call my method `/WeatherForecast` it returns 404.

Whole my code is on the above repo link. Please tell me if you need to attach here directly some code.

[image]

Ofc, when I remove [Authorize] annotaion from my api controller, I can reach the method (enters into a method)

I also read about jhow important is order in Startup class for `app.UseAuthentication; app.UseAuthorization` and I checked that also.

I dont know what else I need to do in order to gain SuccessCode 200.

for those who would like to run it locally from my github repo:

appsettings.Development -> just point to local sql db server and empty database in order to start seeding the data.

client_id: the-big-client
client_secret: secret

please check both scopes (read, write)

Comment: questions need to be self contained.

Comment: sorry, I ddint understand your comment?

Comment: your question can't rely on external links in order to answer the question, you can provide external links as extra information.

Comment: The API looks like you are trying to incorporate IdentityServer into the API itself.  So the IdentityServer project in your repo isn't part of the problem, right?

Comment: yes, Im trying to hold all in one project (webapi) I dont know if the problem is api or identity server..obliviously, I cant hit my methid when I have [Authorize] annotation on my controller and it seems to me that it cant find it at all (404 error)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to use the [Client Credentials flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/client-credentials-flow) to authenticate your API's Swagger... At least, it is the security definition you are adding to Swagger [here](https://github.com/stefancvetkovic/dotnet-api-with-identity-server-db-working/blob/master/my-fancy-api/Startup.cs#L70).

However, as you can see from the link to the explanation of the flow, that requires your `Identity Server` and your `Fancy API` to talk to each other. Therefore, they must be two separate APIs running by themselves. So, you should not add/use all the Identity Server wiring in your `Fancy API`.

The authority against which your Swagger and your API are authenticating - as you define in the [authorization and token URLs](https://github.com/stefancvetkovic/dotnet-api-with-identity-server-db-working/blob/master/my-fancy-api/Startup.cs#L72) - must be that Identity Server.

Moreover, you have the authentication of your API commented out [here](https://github.com/stefancvetkovic/dotnet-api-with-identity-server-db-working/blob/master/my-fancy-api/Startup.cs#L48) - and with an authority different from Swagger -, so you do not seem to be using the token you are receiving. However, you then add authorization [here](https://github.com/stefancvetkovic/dotnet-api-with-identity-server-db-working/blob/master/my-fancy-api/Startup.cs#L56).

The `IdentityServer4` repository has some very good samples to guide us, including one for Client Credentials flow [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/samples/Quickstarts/1_ClientCredentials). This may certainly help you out :)